# iOS7 and GameKit bluetooth

Tags: objective-c

Since I went to the ios 7 on my project, I get an error in the console message:

"2013-11-06 12:29:27.316 battle naval[9399:70b] Bluetooth problem in 32-bit processes on 64-bit system: skipping check"

The connection between my iDevices is no longer.

how to solve this problem?

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

GKPeerPickerController, GKSession and many more are deprecated in iOS7. You should use the Multipeer Connectivity Framework in iOS 7

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html